# OpenGL Invalid enum error when creating glShaderObject

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

I get the invalid enumerant

```
GL Error #1280(invalid enumerant)
```

error with the following code:

```
CHECK_GL_ERROR();
glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
CHECK_GL_ERROR();
```

where the `CHECK_GL_ERROR()` macro is defined as follows:

```
int CheckGLError(char *file, int line)
{  GLenum glErr;
    int    retCode = 0;

    glErr = glGetError();
    while (glErr != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {  const GLubyte* sError = gluErrorString(glErr);

        if (sError)
            cerr << "GL Error #" << glErr << "(" << gluErrorString(glErr) << ") " << " in File " << file << " at line: " << line << endl;
        else
            cerr << "GL Error #" << glErr << " (no message available)" << " in File " << file << " at line: " << line << endl;

        retCode = 1;
        glErr = glGetError();
    }
    return retCode;
}

#define CHECK_GL_ERROR() CheckGLError(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

I'm sure that the problem is generated by the `glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB)` because I've checked with breakpoints that no errors are generated on the first line, but an error is generated after the `glCreateShaderObjectARB()` function.

I'm using glew 1.9.0 and GLUT on Ubuntu 12.04 with NVidia drivers. Has anyone already had this issue?

Comment: Yuck! Do not use the ARB extensions for GLSL, use core GLSL. It went core in OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: So should I change the function to:

`glCreateShaderObject(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);` ?

Comment: No, the function is called `glCreateShader` (no object at the end) and the call would be `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)`. I think that you suffixed it with `…Object` is part of the reason it failed.

Comment: Same error with `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);`...strange

Comment: If that is the macro / function combination you are using to detect GL errors, why does it not print the file / line number? That would be useful information as currently there are two places this check occurs and we have no way of knowing whether the error was generated before or after the call to `glCreateShader (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual answer, but it would be way too long to write in the form of a comment... I have a suspicion that you are not running in a proper HW accelerated context.

Could you add the following code to your program and include the output in your question?

```
#include <cstdio>

...

const GLubyte* vendor   = glGetString (GL_VENDOR);
const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER);
const GLubyte* version  = glGetString (GL_VERSION);
const GLubyte* glsl_ver = glGetString (GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);

printf ( "%s : %s (%s)\n >> GLSL: %s\n",
           vendor,
             renderer,
               version,
                 glsl_ver );
```

It should produce output like this (from my OS X 10.6 laptop):

```
NVIDIA Corporation : NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M OpenGL Engine (2.1 NVIDIA-1.6.36)
 >> GLSL: 1.20
```